# Checkbox Issues- Checboxes not show when export to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

I want to show check boxes when export to PDF using C#. I also use

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{    
     //return;   
}
```

I tried to solve my problem.. But code only give value of checkbox means true or false. This is all my code which i have tried so far...

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrepareControlForExport(Vesseldetail);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Export.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    Vesseldetail.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    frm.Controls.Add(Vesseldetail);
    frm.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();

}

private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        Control current = control.Controls[i];
        if (current is LinkButton)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
        }
        else if (current is ImageButton)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
        }
        else if (current is HyperLink)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
        }
        else if (current is DropDownList)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
        }
        else if (current is CheckBox)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? " True" : " False"));
            current.Visible = true;

        }

        if (current.HasControls())
        {
            pdfconverter.PrepareControlForExport(current); //pdfconverter is  class.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you export to PDF ? Is there any checkbox exist on form ? can you show your full source code so that we can help you better

Comment: Your method body is empty, try putting something there

Comment: _not work_ is **never** enough information for explaining a problem. You didn't _even_ show your real work and what have you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Show your code and the errors you get or obstacles you face with

Answer (score 0):

```
static string path;
    path = Server.MapPath("~/Styles/images/");
    private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "<br><img  src='" + path + "checked.png' alt=''width='15' height='15' float='right' />" : "<br><img border='10' src='" + path + "unchecked.png' alt=''width='15' height='15' float='right' />"));

                current.Visible = true;

            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                VesselDetails.PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
```